# How do I add new keys and value to an array before converting to JSON?

Tags: php, laravel, datatables

How do I add additional key and value to my array in every loop before converting it to json?

I'm trying to add a additional key and value to accommodate the 'Edit' and 'Delete" button before converting it on JS DataTables.

My sample current array

**$results:**

```
array:97 [
 0 => {#1
  +"username": "azura"
  +"gem": "emerald"
  +"color": null
 }

 1 => {#2
  +"username": "azuren"
  +"gem": "ruby"
  +"color": "red"
 }
...]
```

My expected array after adding. I want to inject a button made of string.

```
 0 => {#1
  +"username": "azura"
  +"gem": "emerald"
  +"color": null
  +"action": "<button id="edit" class="edit-btn></button>
              <button id="remove" class="delete-btn">Delete</button>"
 }

 1 => {#2
  +"username": "anngeetan"
  +"gem": "ruby"
  +"color": "red"
  +"action": "<button id="edit" class="edit-btn></button>
              <button id="remove" class="delete-btn">Delete</button>"
 }
...]
```

Then on my larvel php i will convert it to DataTables Json to accomodate the new 'action' item to my js

My js

```
$('#mytable').DataTable({
 columns: [
     'data': 'azuren',
     'data': 'gem',
     'data': 'color',
     'data': 'action',
 ]
}):
```

My php controller

```
public function get_table(Request $request)
{
    $table = $request['selected-table'];
    $results = DB::select("SELECT * from $table");
    
    //add the 'action' item somewhere here.

    return datatables($results)->make(true);
}
```

PS: Feel free to suggest a new method if there a better way or the optimization is bad ( I also have an array that has 20,000 entries).

Comment: shared your tried code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this way

https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/add-column

```
$table = $request['selected-table'];
$results = DB::select("SELECT * from $table");

 return datatables($results)
     ->addColumn('action', function ($row) { // added action key 
          return "<button id='edit' class='edit-btn'></button>
                 <button id='remove' class='delete-btn'>Delete</button>";
     })->make(true);
```

Comment: This code works like magic. Additional Question how do you add a reference element to the buttons each row? Like if i click delete on this specific row how can i reference that row to the button?